# posting data to server and get response. i want individual response of first name, email. please see below code once

Tags: android, json, post

[image]

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("my result:"+result);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String fname = jsonObject.getString("First_Name");
                String lname = jsonObject.getString("Last_Name");
                String mail = jsonObject.getString("Email");
                System.out.println("fname:"+fname+" lname:"+lname+" email:"+mail);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

In the above code, 
posting data to server and get response. i want individual response of first name, email. can you please rectify my mistake.

Comment: Your result is in JSONObject format and you are trying to convert it into JSONArray that is why you are getting type missmatch exception remove that code it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You should parse as JSONObject, not as JsonArray as per your response from the server.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("my result:"+result);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String fname = jsonObject.optString("First_Name");
            String lname = jsonObject.optString("Last_Name");
            String mail = jsonObject.optString("Email");
            System.out.println("fname:"+fname+" lname:"+lname+" email:"+mail);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```